# Retrieving all responses from Typeform using Response API

Tags: typeform

I'm attempting to retrieve all responses from Typeform for a survey using the "before" and "after" querystring parameters as documented here: https://developer.typeform.com/responses/walkthroughs/#use-query-parameters-to-retrieve-specific-data

I'd rather not use "since" and "until" because I may have more than 1000 responses in a day (and the docs indicate that before/after should be used in this case.)  The token-based approach seems cleaner at any rate.

My problem is that I'm never able to retrieve a set of results that line up with the "total_items" value that is returned in the first call.  Maybe my expectations are incorrect?  I wind up with a value that is several hundred short of that.  Code excerpt below.  I'm including an empty "before" query string parameter in the first call since the docs indicate that the presence of that parameter changes the ordering to align with their process-order (as opposed to submit order).

```js
async getAllResults(formId) {
    const opts = {
      ...this._opts,
      url: `https://api.typeform.com/forms/${formId}/responses?page_size=1000&before`
    }

    let results = (await axios.request(opts)).data
    let allResults = results.items

    const totalResponseCount = results.total_items

    while (results.items.length > 0) {
      const lastToken = _.last(results.items).token
      results = (await axios.request({ ...opts, url: opts.url + `=${lastToken}` })).data
      allResults = _.concat(allResults, results.items)
    }

    // Fails
    assert.ok(allResults.length === totalResponseCount)

    return allResults
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the code myself, and looks like there is always an extra result that gets added at the end. Making it a duplicate result in your `allResults` array and making the length off by one.

isn't the `while` loop should be continuing until `allResults.length === totalResponseCount`?

so code would be:

```js
while (allResults.length != totalResponseCount && results.items.length > 0) {
  const lastToken = _.last(results.items).token
  results = (await axios.request({ ...opts, url: opts.url + `=${lastToken}` })).data
  allResults = _.concat(allResults, results.items)
}
```

what do yo think?

Comment: Well, I'm looping until results.items.length === 0 because eventually you get a response from typeform that looks like below.  But in my case, the code above will net about ~3800 results when the count reported by total_items is ~4100.
{
    "total_items": 0,
    "page_count": 0,
    "items": []
}

Comment: Could it be because some of the responses were not completed?

Add `&completed=true`, do the results match?

Comment: This was a good thought - but using &completed=true actually just yields a different number than either of the other two.  Thanks for your thoughts on this though Nicolas.